# Linking Foreign key between tables in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am just starting out with Django and so please help me out with my doubt. Currently, I have three tables Topic, Webpage, and AccessRecord. In the third table *AccessRecord*, I have used a ForeignKey with the second table *Webpage*. But Webpage table has three attributes topic, name, and URL ..so my doubt is which attribute of these three will be treated as a Foreign key to *AccessRecord* table.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class Topic(models.Model):

    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique = True)

    def __str__(self):

        return(self.top_name)

class Webpage(models.Model):

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):

    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the ForeignKey relationship is from `AccessRecord` to `Webpage` object, that only resides in `AccessRecord`. There is no direct relation between a `Webpage` to a `AccessRecord` **object**. Instead, django provides a [**`reverse relationship`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) where you can access **queryset** of `AccessRecord` from a `Webpage` object. Like this:

```
webpage = Webpage.objects.first()  # an object
records = webpage.accessrecord_set.all() # a queryset
```

If you iterate through `records` variable given above, you shall get `AccessRecord` object. Like this:

```
for record in records:
    print(record) # an AccessRecord object
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I agree with you on this ForeignKey relationship is between AccessRecord and Webpage. My doubt is what is the primary key then in Wepage..? It would be great if you could explain me sir

Comment: The field name is `name_id`. Django creates a new field with foreignkey's name + `_id`. If you check the database, you should see a column like this.

Answer (score 1):

Truth is the foreign key relationship goes this way

Topic -(1------many)->webpage --(1------------many)-> Accessrecord

In this situation, Accessrecord is also linked to Topic through webpage.
Django will also automatically create a primary key for you.
I also notice something intriguing while playing about with Django ORM.
Note that what you set on the def **str**: method is what the foreign key field will be filled with.
i.e.
your model webpage returns self.name, the field name from inheriting model Accsessrecord will have options from the self.name.
It cant be filled manually, this way Django maintains data integrity.

You can play around it on your admin page as well.

## Hopelly this also helps

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning about def __str__.. this cleared my doubt